# Animating and re-animating controls via a queue

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a custom control I call "ControlFader". It inherits from the Selector primitive. Items added to the control are placed into a single grid as overlapping controls. The goal is to have an animation where the selected item is faded in and the previously selected item is faded out.

To start, I supply a custom item container (of type ControlFaderItem) which has its opacity set to zero. The following code is used to create the storyboard (FadeTime is defined elsewhere):

```
private Storyboard CreateStoryboard(ControlFaderItem sourceItem, ControlFaderItem targetItem)
{
    var fadeControlsStoryboard = new Storyboard();

    if (sourceItem != null)
    {
        var sourceAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, FadeTime);
        sourceAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, sourceItem);
        sourceAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        fadeControlsStoryboard.Children.Add(sourceAnimation);
    }

    if (targetItem != null)
    {
        var targetAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, FadeTime);
        targetAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, targetItem);
        targetAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        fadeControlsStoryboard.Children.Add(targetAnimation);
    }

    return fadeControlsStoryboard;
}
```

I added a queue to indicate which item is to be faded next. Items are removed from the queue using this method:

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
    if (isFadeAnimating)
        return;

    // can't process if there are no queued items
    if (FadeQueue.Count == 0)
        return;

    // get the next item to fade to
    var nextItem = FadeQueue.Dequeue();

    // locate the index of the item
    var itemIndex = Items.IndexOf(nextItem);

    if (itemIndex != -1)
        SelectedIndex = itemIndex;
}
```

I override the OnSelectionChanged event where I:

1. check if a fade is already happening and queue items if it is
2. start a fade

It looks like this:

```
protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // code to simulate an OnSelectionChanging is here (removed for brevity)
    // it's used to queue a new selection if isFadeAnimating is true, and reverse the selection

    // code to obtain source and target container item also removed for brevity

    if (isFadeAnimating)
        return;

    isFadeAnimating = true;

    var storyboard = CreateStoryboard(sourceItem, targetItem);
    storyboard.Completed += (s, arg) =>
    {
        if (sourceItem != null)
            sourceItem.Opacity = 0d;

        isFadeAnimating = false;
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

        ProcessQueue();
    };

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

For some odd reason, the call to ProcessQueue from inside the storyboard completed event seems to break the storyboard. But only if the right sequence of fades is executed.

If I fade from index 0 to 1 then back to 0 quickly enough, the fades stop working. It has to be quick enough that the fade back to 0 is attempted while the first fade is occurring (therefore placing it on the queue).

In a Window where I'm using the ControlFader, to trigger the fades I bind to the SelectedIndex of the ControlFader. The binding stops updating after the fades from index 0 to 1 then back to 0.

When I remove the call to ProcessQueue, the animation and binding never break, but my fades are not in sync (they fall behind) with what should be the current SelectedIndex since the queue isn't being processed.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ListBoxItem` has `Selected` and `Unselected` visual states, why not use them?

Comment: @Xin Interesting suggestion, but how then would I prevent a further selection (add the next item to the queue) if one of the state animations is taking place?

Comment: How about just disabling the selection during the state animations?

Comment: @Xin In one use of my control, the selected index is being bound to an enum indicating the state of a downloading image. When in state 1 (Downloading) the ControlFader shows a progress bar, when in state 2 (Downloaded) the ControlFader should fade from the progress bar to the actual image. There are other states, and other reasons for them to be triggered (user interactions such as hitting refresh while a download is in progress). Since the state can change, often and rapidly, I can't simply ignore or block the selected index from being updated. This is why I introduced the queue.

Comment: I'm not understanding why a state animation has to "complete" between item selections.  Why can't this happen: 

User clicks on Item1 (Item1 start fadeIn); 
User quickly clicks Item2 (Item1 don't finish fadeIn just start fadeOut, Item2 start fadeIn); 
User quickly clicks Item1 (Item2 start fadeOut, Item1 start fadeIn)

Comment: The user is not controlling the selection. The selection is bound to an enum type used to determine the state of another object type. However, I'll revisit the idea of the VSM when I get a chance and see if I can make it work. I don't think it will, but it's worth attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in my ProcessQueue method was the problem:

```
SelectedIndex = itemIndex;
```

Because I had setup a binding on SelectedIndex, by assigning it inside the controls code, my binding was being removed. Since this was inside the ProcessQueue method, the problem only started to showed up when there were queued items.

I fixed it by using selected item instead:

```
SelectedItem = nextItem;
```

Since I never set any binding expressions on SelectedItem, the bug is never hit.